# How to remove padding from a Object List Item?

Tags: css, sapui5

I have a List with grouped Object List Items in it. [Like here in the Explored App](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.ObjectListItem/samples), click on Samples. Now every of those items have a padding of `1rem`, given by the css with the selector `.sapMLIB.sapMObjLItem` .

Now I wanted to reduce the top and the bottom padding to `0.25rem`, so I added a
class to the Object and imported a custom css (via `manifest.json`), all as described [in the Walkthrough](https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/723f4b2334e344c08269159797f6f796.html). It did not work as the normal css overwrites my custom one.

An other try was to add the class `sapUiNoContentPadding` to the elements, but also the css rules behind that get overwritten by the rules described in the first paragraph.

**What am I doing wrong? how to remove that padding without rewriting the renderer?**

MyView:

```
<mvc:View
  controllerName="sap.ui.xxxx.someapp.controller.MyList"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
  <StandardListItem title="Titel"/>
  <List class="sapUiResponsiveMargin sapUiNoContentPadding"
    width="auto"
    items="{path : '//elementsSet',
      sorter : {
        path : 'attribute1}',
        group : true
      }
    }">  
    <items>
      <ObjectListItem title="{= ${attribute1} === '' ? 'Enter Text Please' : ${attribute1}}"
        icon="{= ${attribute1} === '' ? 'sap-icon://alert' : 'sap-icon://sys-enter'}"
        number="{attribute4}"
        numberUnit="$"
        numberState="{=  ${attribute4} > 10 ? 'Error' : 'Success' }"
        type="Active" press="onItemPress"
        markFlagged="true" markFavorite="true"
        showMarkers="true" 
        class="sapUiNoContentPadding myownclassforpadding">
        <firstStatus>
          <ObjectStatus
            text="some text" />
        </firstStatus>
        <attributes>
        <ObjectAttribute text="{attribute1}" visible="false"/>
        <ObjectAttribute text="{attribute2}"/>
        <ObjectAttribute text="{attribute3}" visible="false"/>
        <ObjectAttribute text="{attribute4}" visible="false"/>
        </attributes>
      </ObjectListItem>
    </items>
  </List>
</mvc:View>
```

my css

```
.myownclassforpadding{
    padding: 0;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS class `myownclassforpadding` will not be used, because CSS from the library is more specific as it uses two classes `sapMLIB` and `sapMObjLItem`.
You can make your CSS more specific this way:

```
.sapMLIB.sapMObjLItem.myownclassforpadding{
   padding: 0;
   background-color: green;
}
```

Have a look at the [JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/jexujoguwa/1/edit?html,css,js,output).

Answer (score 2):

Try the below selector to override default css.

```
.sapMLIB.sapMObjLItem.myownclassforpadding{
    padding-top: 0.25rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: why? what are the thoughts?

Comment: to make it more specific. refer this document for detail understanding: https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/723f4b2334e344c08269159797f6f796.html

Answer (score 1):

If you write `!important` after the properties you want to change, it will overwrite the `sapUI5` class properties.

For example:

```
.myownclassforpadding{
    padding: 0 !important;
    background-color: green !important;
}
```

This will make your padding and background-color properties take precedence over `sapUI5`.

Comment: This is not a good solution. Please, don't just use `!important` when there are stable ways to do it.

Comment: @inetphantom Using `!important` often leads to a **snowball effect**. If an element with `!important` needs to be overridden, the developer is forced to use `!important` again. Another reason is the risk of **naming collision**. We cannot guarantee that no one will ever use the same name for their style classes. A well-defined group of selectors can avoid that. There are, however, valid reasons to use `!important` but they do not apply to UI5 app developers as the keyword is [**not intended** to be used as a "quick fix"](https://medium.com/markuptips/css-is-important-960a9921e454).